# I need some advice with inheritance and downcast

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I need some help with inheritance and cast:

```
public Class1 { public int myVar1;}
public Class2 : Class1 { public int myVar2;}

public void MyMethod(){ 
    Class1 myC1 = new Class1() { myVar1 = 10;} 
    Class2 myC2 = new Class2() { myVar2 = 15;}
    // What i should do here to achieve next
    Console.WriteLine(myC2.myVar1); // myVar1 = 10
}
```

What I want to do is to get `myVar1` value of `10` from `myC2`, so that when I call `myC2.myVar1` it is 10 and when I call `myC2.myVar2` it is 15

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want. `myC1` and `myC2` are two different instances (and they do not share fields). If you want `myC2.myVar1` to be 10, you will have to assign it somewhere: `myC2.myVar1 = 10;` or `myC2.myVar1 = myC1.myVar1;`. I don't see what this has to do with downcasting either.

Comment: Class1 is base clas of Class2, when i assign value to base class instance how i should cast to derived class, so that derived class keeps this value

Comment: You can't assign a base class to a derived class. Consider `Cat x = new Mammal()` It won't work because it's *not* a Cat. However, you can assign a derived to a base, `Mammal y = new Cat()` because it *is* a Mammal, and then you can assign that to the derived class after `Cat x = (Cat)y`; because it *is* a Cat. We have to explicitly cast (putting the type name in parentheses) because it's a narrowing cast that could fail if e.g. `Cat x = (Cat)(new Dog())` which is valid but not going to work, because the Dog is not a Cat.

Comment: Clear explanation, thank you ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`myC2.myVar1` has a value of 0 because you didn't set it and `int` fields default to `0`.

If you want `myC2.myVar1` to be `10`, then set it:

```
var myC2 = new Class2{myVar1 = 10, myVar2 = 15};
```

Setting `myC1.myVar1` to 10 won't affect it as it's another instance entirely. Just as you can be called Dimitri and I can be called Jon because we're different people so our `Name` property doesn't overwrite each others.

Perhaps though you can get the effect you want by not creating a `Class1` at all; if you use:

```
var myC2 = new Class2{myVar1 = 10, myVar2 = 15};
Class1 myC1 = myC2;
```

Then they `myC1` and `myC2` will be two references to exactly the same instance, because it's legal to hold a reference to an object in a variable of a base type.

Comment: I got it about setting inherited variable or keeping derived class reference, but if i have just two instances, one of base class and second of derived class, i took and assigned to a variable of an instance of base class 5, than what i should do that when i go and call this variable that inherits derived class it is 5.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class2 myC2 = new Class2 { myVar1 = 10; myVar2 = 15;}
```

You've made  completely seperate instances. From the above, you should be able to just call myC2.myVar1 and myC2.myVar2 to retrieve these values.

Because 'Class2' instances inherit 'Class1', 'Class2' contains 'Class1' fields.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several very different things you want, but this seems to follow your description

```
    public class Class1 
    {
        internal static int Myvar;
        private int _myVar;
        public int MyVar1
        {
            get{return this.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Class1)) ? Myvar : _myVar;}
            set{_myVar = value;Myvar = value;}
        }
    }
    public class Class2 : Class1
    {
        public int MyVar2 { get; set; }
    }
```

In case you have

```
var myC1 = new Class1 { MyVar1 = 10 };
var myC2 = new Class2 { MyVar2 = 15 }; //myC2.MyVar1 = 10
var myC3 = new Class1 { MyVar1 = 11 }; //myC2.MyVar1 = 11; myC1.MyVar1 = 10
```

Comment: I wrote it some time back as an example of multiple inheritance.

Comment: Let's say they all will be age of 40 if i will set variable personAge of base class instance to 40, how it should be done?

Comment: @Dimitri Example 1 sets default value. Example 2 sets default value that can change during time of execution.

Comment: I don't want to use default values or static fields in base class, all i want to achieve is that when i assign value to an instance variable of base class, this value automatically to be assigned  to an inherited variable of base class in instance of derived class.

Comment: @Dimitri Created version 4 that should do what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to define `Class1` as:

```
public class Class1
{
  public Class1()
  {
    myVar1 = 10;
  }
  public int myVar1;
}
```

so the default value of `myVar1` is 10 when `Class1` constructor is executed.